# How does xkb compilation work?

Tags: xorg, xkb

In a kind of "Linux from scratch" environment I have the problem that xkbcomp fails on startup of X. I found that I even can't compile keymaps on my standard Ubuntu machine:

```
xkbcomp -w 10 -R/usr/share/X11/xkb -xkm rules/evdev dummy.km
```

This results in the error:

```
Warning: Changing root directory to "/usr/share/X11/xkb"
syntax error: line 16 of rules/evdev
last scanned symbol is:
Errors encountered in rules/evdev; not compiled.
```

How is xkbcomp supposed to be used?

Comment: Sorry, the error message would have been helpful - added now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev` contains a specification of *rules*. Rules tell XKB how to build keymaps from part, they don't specify a particular keymap. The input of `xkbcomp` needs to be a *keymap*.

The easiest way to figure out what the input should be is to
<s>read the [man page](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xkbcomp.1.xhtml)</s> (haha no)
<s>read the [official documentation](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Config.html)</s> (as if)
<s>read the misleadingly named [Unreliable guide](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node5.html#SECTION00058200000000000000)</s> (which is so good it's linked on the semi-official [X.org wiki](https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/), but while it does [have the information](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node5.html#SECTION00058200000000000000) it's not actually stated that this is the input for `xkbcomp`)
errr, ask on the Internet? Oh, you just did that.

Well, `xkbcomp` works both ways. So if you just ask it to decompile the keymap from your display, you'll see some acceptable input.

```
xkbcomp :0 - | less
```

The syntax is:

```
xkb_keymap {
  xkb_keycodes { … };
  xkb_types    { … };
  xkb_compat   { … };
  xkb_symbols  { … };
  xkb_geometry { … };
}
```

The content of the braces after `xkb_xxx` are things that go into files in the directories `/usr/share/X11/xkb/xxx`. You can use an `include` statement to tell `xkbcomp` to read existing files. Note that you need a single `include` directive with `+` between file names. Some files contain multiple `xkb_xxx` directives, pass the name of the one you want in parentheses. For example, to use the US layout with `Compose` on <kbd>Menu</kbd>, use

```
xkb_symbols { include "us+compose(menu)" }
```

You can ask [`setxkbmap`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.xhtml) to produce acceptable input for `xkbcomp`. Pass the `-print` option to see the output rather than push the keymap to the server. With `setxkbmap`, pass `-compat`, `-geometry`, `-keycodes` and `-types` to set the corresponding `xkb_xxx`, and `-layout` for `xkb_symbols`.

```
setxkbmap -layout "us+compose(menu)" -print
```

Actually, I lied by omission above, there's an easier way: the information is on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension#Local_XKB_folder). If you like understanding how to configure your system, the Arch wiki is an excellent resource, whether you're using Arch Linux or not.

Comment: `-layout "us,compose(menu)"` appears to result in the `compose(menu)` option used for the Group 2 layout; this is probably not what you want.  (this syntax is used to specify up to 4 languages to be switched between, so `-layout us,de,ru,se` or similar.)  you want `-layout us -option compose:menu`.  compare your version's `+compose(menu):2` with the `-option`'s `+compose(menu)`.

Comment: @quixotic Oh, right, thanks. I simiplified this from my own configuration, which works for me, but I actually had `+` in there, not `,`. Fixed.